# How to create and access extra space on USB Stick?

Tags: 11.10, usb, live-usb

I used the Ubuntu 11.10 iso and did a dd to create a LiveUSB.  I also used gParted to assign the extra space to a second VFAT partition.  Is there any way to mount the additional space while running from the LiveUSB image on the same device?

When I try I get an error that the device is busy? My steps were the same as those documented at this site: http://www.tuxgarage.com/2011/06/ubuntu-switched-to-hybrid-disc-images.html.  I also noticed that when I insert this USB into a windows machine I'm unable to access the VFAT section of USB.

Is there anyway to mount sdb2 under Windows?

Comment: why didnt you use the easy way of creating usb disk i.e "System->Administration->Create a USB startup disk"?

Comment: Using Create USB startup disk does not allow the liveUSB to access an additional partition that would also be available to Windows.

Answer (score 1):

use disk utility to first see which partitions have been created and then you may modify them.Formatting alone the pen drive will not do.